# ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges in Pandas 'Cut()'

Tags: python, pandas, binning

I'm using cut() in Pandas to categorize the values of a numerical column.

```
df['bmi_bin']=pd.cut(df['Body Mass Index'],bins=4,labels=[0,1,2,3])
```

Output:

```
0      2
1      2
2      1
3      2
4      1
      ..
683    1
690    0
694    1
696    0
699    1
```

I tried putting the same code in a loop:

```
num_of_bins=4

for i in range(0,num_of_bins):
            df['bmi_bin']=pd.cut(df['Body Mass Index'],bins=num_of_bins, labels=[i])
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
ValueError: Bin labels must be one fewer than the number of bin edges
```

Where did I go wrong? Doesn't labels[i] give label values [0,1,2,3] which are fewer than 4?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Same as the output mentioned under the first line of code, i.e., 0/1/2/3.

Comment: I think you need to give a bigger picture of what you are trying to do here.   Using a for loop here doesn't make much sense, at least to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is trying to split dataframe into diff bins with lable. But bins and lables count not matching.
In for loop you are spliting dataframe into 0, 1,2,3 bins in different iteration but lable is only one at a time whether its 0, 1,2 or 3.
If you want to use loop then below can be used but not sure what output you are expecting -

```
num_of_bins=4
lt=[]
for i in range(0,num_of_bins):
    lt.append(i)
    df['bmi_bin']=pd.cut(df['Body Mass Index'],bins=i, labels=lt)
```

Comment: Have you tried to run this? What is the point of doing it in the loop?

Comment: It was not about logic, it was for syntax match.. in loop... she wanted to have it in a loop.. thats why I put code like that...